# On redirect from Idp the BrowserRouter doesnt rerender when the previous url from state redirects from the redirect from the idp

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, auth0

I have a react app set up with Auth0

When an anonymous user directly navigate to a protected page

```
http://localhost:3000/appname/ProtectedPage
```

the code at the bottom of my component (Auth0 supplied lib)

```
export default withAuthenticationRequired(ProtectedPage , {
  // Show a message while the user waits to be redirected to the login page.
  onRedirecting: () => (<div>Redirecting you to the login page...</div>),
});
```

redirects the user to the Auth0 login page

On successful login the user is redirected back to the authorised redirect url  (http://localhost:3000/appname )

The auth0 library passes state back and the original url is loaded into the browser.

The url at this point looks like

```
http://localhost:3000/appname?code=asdasdadasdadasd
```

after this the original url is extracted from the state  and the app redirects to the desired page

```
http://localhost/appname/ProtectedPage
```

This behaviour is what i want so far.

The issue is I have a BrowserRouter which renders when the original response is returned to

```
http://localhost:3000/appname?code=asdasdadasdadasd
```

This this renders the HomeComponent

A bit more info

I have two components

The first component contains the BrowserRouter

and has this effect

```
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(`Called useEffect from FI ${window.location.pathname}`);
  }, [window.location.pathname]);
```

The second component (a menu component) is rendered in the BrowserRouter but before the switch
and has this useEffect

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const path = window.location.pathname;
    console.log(`Called useEffect from FMH  ${path}`);
    setActiveItem(path);
  }, [window.location.pathname]);
```

I also have used a DebugRouter to try and render some more details from the Browser Router

on redirect from the idp I get the following console outputs

```
initial history is:  {
  "length": 26,
  "action": "POP",
  "location": {
    "pathname": "/appname",
    "search": "?code=12345&state=iamastate",
    "hash": ""
  }
}
VM188 main.chunk.js:500 Called useEffect from FMH  /appname
VM188 main.chunk.js:173 Called useEffect from FI /appname
VM188 main.chunk.js:500 Called useEffect from FMH  /appname/ProtectedPage
```

Again the ProtectedPage changes but the BrowserRouter doesnt render the correct component

I think the lifecycle seems to be

```
Redirect received /appname?code 
BrowserRouter begings rendering 
Url is changed by auth component 
Menu component renders and sees the changed url
Browser Router finishes rendering with original url
```

Possibly the useEffect should react to a change from auth lib but again not sure how to catch it

React-newbie thanks again

Comment: you can insert url as dependency in your useEffect array. So when the url changes the component will re-render.

Comment: Hey thanks , updated the question after trying use effect, but its still not working as expected